# Calculate the difference between two times (including millseconds) in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a simple bash script which outputs two timestamps per line like so:

```
10:25:48,192 10:25:46,967
10:25:48,522 10:25:48,200
10:25:49,418 10:25:48,531
```

I'd like to refine the script to calculate the difference (in milliseconds) between the two timestamps on each line. How can this be done?

Comment: This might help with GNU date: milliseconds since the epoch: `date +%s%3N`

Comment: Ah, thanks. This might help me with an awk approach I'm trying to get working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -i d1 d2 diff    # set integer flag

while IFS=":, " read -r h1 m1 s1 x1 h2 m2 s2 x2; do
  # force decimal numbers without leading zeros and calculate milliseconds
  d1=$((10#$h1))*60*60*1000+$((10#$m1))*60*1000+$((10#$s1))*1000+$((10#$x1))
  d2=$((10#$h2))*60*60*1000+$((10#$m2))*60*1000+$((10#$s2))*1000+$((10#$x2))
  diff=$d1-$d2
  echo $diff
done < file
```

Output:

```
1225
322
887
```

With awk:

```
awk -F '[:, ]' '{print ($1*60*60*1000+$2*60*1000+$3*1000+$4)-($5*60*60*1000+$6*60*1000+$7*1000+$8)}' file
```

Comment: Thanks! Close, but failed for input 06:54:02,009 06:54:01,360. value too great for base (error token is "09")

Comment: Thanks! You got there faster than I could with awk, so you win ;)

Comment: I‘ve added an awk version, too.